# Do any chip architectures feature instruction primitives for complex numbers?

Tags: computer-architecture

Just curious if there are any computer chips with builtin operations for manipulating Complex numbers, or if one must roll their own using Real ops for now.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. It was my understanding that complex numbers and most of the various things you can do with them could be done with matrix operations, such as those available in processors supporting SSE or later (Pentium III or newer). Though the P4 and newer with SSE2 or newer supports double precision values and more matrix/vector sizes.

Answer (score 2):

#### Are any computer chips with builtin operations for manipulating Complex numbers?

Several papers have been published that include designs and simulations for such chips, however, as far as I am aware none have actually been manufactured.

Examples:

- [Arithmetic Unit for Complex Number Processing](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.102.8292&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- [DESIGN AND IMPLEMENTATION OF COMPLEX FLOATING POINT PROCESSOR USING FPGA](http://aircconline.com/vlsics/V4N5/4513vlsi04.pdf)

Comment: For Cartesian representation, wouldn't addition be merely 2-way SIMD addition and multiplication be a helpful primitive for matrix multiplication?

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton No idea. Outside my area of expertise :)